Print a 120 page word document as 30 separate 4 page folded booklets
I have a 624 page document which is made of 156 separate 4 page documents. I want to print pages 1-4 as an A5 folded booklet (i.e. one sheet of A4 folded), then pages 5-8 as a folded booklet etc. to obtain 156 4 page folded booklets. All the pages are unique.
I have used booklet settings, staple and fold settings, and told it to do 'fold only' and chosen 4 sheets but all that happens is it prints the whole thing as one booklet but not stapled. Pages 1 and 2 are fine, but pages 3 and 4 are on a different sheet whereas I want pages 1,2,3,4 on the same sheet. And actually I don't care if they are folded I just need every 4 lots of A4 pages to be printed booklet style on the same sheet of A4 and for this to happen for the whole document.
Is there a way?
Thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I fixed it - you have to do "fold only" and select "1 sheet"

Is this document being created using the Mail Merge feature, starting with a 4-page primary merge document?

Welcome Mrs Carlile! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

check if Print&Share can do it, probably it can split it.
